# run javascript in already open tab through the inspect element console using python?

Tags: javascript, python, inspect-element

I'm attempting to execute code within the console of Inspect Element using Python, within an already open tab window. However, my code opens a new browser window instead.

To clarify, I wrote an example to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, but it resulted in the opening of a new browser window.

this is my experimental code:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("www.example.com")

start_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton_StartNormal")
start_button.click()

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.